# List files current user can edit using Google Drive API

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the Google Drive API in Javascript to get a list of files that the signed in user can edit. How do I do this?

I've tried using a files/list request to get the list of files which gets a list of all files by default: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

The request also accepts search parameters:
https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters

e.g. to search for files writeable by the user "test@example.org" use 'test@example.org' in writers

I need to be able to say ' [current user's email address] in writers' or something similar for this to work though and I can't see any way to programmatically get the current user's email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to do that with a query like:

```
'user@example.com' in owners or 'user@example.com' in writers
```

That'll return files the current user either owns or it where it was shared with them with edit permissions.

Comment: I need the current user's email address for that to work though. How would I do that?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login for details on obtaining the user's profile info & email address.

Comment: Is there OR operation? I see only AND.